# indexing sorted alignment file with samtools index gives "Exec format error"

Tags: sorting, indexing, alignment, samtools

I am struggling with samtools index.

I already did the alignment using `"bwa mem reference.fa seq.fastq > alg.sam"`.

The resulting sam file was converted to bam format using `"samtools view -S -h -b alg.sam > alg.bam"`.

Next, the files were sorted by using `"sort -h alg.bam >sorted.bam"`.

And now we come to the problem: `"samtools index -b sorted.bam"` always returns the following error:

> "failed to open file "sorted.bam" : Exec format error samtools index:
> failed to open "sorted.bam": Exec format error"

I read that the samtools version 1.9 returns this error quite often. However, I have samtools version 1.10 installed and still could not find a way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the mistake. We need to write
"samtools sort alg.bam -o sorted.bam"
The output can then be used as input for samtools index